# Visual Basic and Resolution/Zoom?

Tags: vb.net, screen-resolution

Is it possible to change the resolution of the form without changing the resolution of the computer?

And if not, then I suppose I'll ask, how would I be able to zoom/blow up the form to make it bigger?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Resolution" isn't anything that really applies to forms. What exactly are you trying to do? If you're trying to make the form bigger, you can increase its Size attribute in the Properties window. If you're trying to make the controls and font bigger, you'll need to modify the Font attributes for all the controls as well as their Size attribute.

Comment: I'm trying to make something bigger that can't be re-sized in that way.
It's a Flash element that is has a fixed screen size.